# c# DrawString - measure bounding boxes for each character

Tags: c#, gdi+

Before I pass a string to Graphics.DrawString(), I'd like to know exactly where each character will be - not just it's offset and width, but its exact bound box with ascent/descent figured in so that I can do collision detection at the character level rather than using the entire line-height that Graphics.MeasureString() is giving me.

I can't seem to find any examples for this that accurately return the bounding box for each character. How can this be done in c#/GDI+ ?

Ideally, I'd like to get each of the gray Rectangles as in this image:

[image]

Comment: where is your `character` painted? I hope that's not a character in a `RichTextBox` or `TextBox` because that's not easy at all to deal with characters in textboxes.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2118/Bypass-Graphics-MeasureString-limitations.  It looks like you're looking for `graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges`?

Comment: I found this article but MeasureCharacterRanges() doesn't vary with height for each char in the string - it gives the entire line height for each.

Comment: Ah.  Sorry.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: The help page is vague, but maybe GlyphTypeface.AdvanceHeights ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.advanceheights.aspx  (Sorry, I'm not at a point where I can experiment with it myself to tell you more.)

Comment: Why don't you just measure each character individually? Don't make the problem more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to accurately measure characters within a string in GDI+. Even if you forget subpixel positioning and kerning, etc, which mean that characters in the drawn string will be different sizes depending on their context in the string and position on screen and ClearType settings, MeasureString has a habit of adding padding and fudge factors so you can't easily get the desired info out of it.

One approach that sortof works is to Measure the first character, then the first two characters, then the first three characters, and so on, so that you get a rough idea where they will all end up when drawn in a single hit. Then you'll probably need to Measure each char again to determine its height. If MeasureString doesn't give the char height but gives the font height instead, you might have to resort to rendering each character to an offscreen bitmap and then scanning the pixels to determine the true height of the character.

At that point you may find it's better to p/invoke off to a lower level font API that just gives you the information you need directly from the font. But then you'll probably need to use something other than GDO+ to render it as the chances of it lining up with what you've worked out may not be good.

(can you tell that I have a trust issue with the quality off the GDI+ font renderer yet?)

Comment: You're not the only one. The GDI+ font renderer is garbage, that's why no one uses it except for the poor WinForms programmers who don't know any better. `TextRenderer.DrawText` is a *much* better option. It wraps GDI, which has gotten text right since about 1987.

Comment: @CodyGray `poor WinForms programmers who don't know any better` - Comments like this are not helpful and should not be posted on SO.  For specific projects WinForms may be the better choice over others such as WPF.

Comment: @deegee I *am* a WinForms programmer. I rather dislike WPF, and continue to use WinForms. It wasn't one of those annoying comments about how WinForms sucks; I don't believe that at all. The point was simply that the WinForms `Graphics` class is a wrapper around GDI+ (not GDI) and that there is an obviously-named `DrawString` method that programmers who do not know any better try to use to draw text. That is a mistake, they should be using the obscure `TextRenderer.DrawText` method, which wraps GDI, to draw text. It's just that they don't know about it because it is obscure. Sorry to mislead.

Comment: @CodyGray - My apologies for misunderstanding your previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This is the solution I used, building on @Sayka's example and a trick to get actual char width:

If you're drawing a string at X, Y using Font in Graphics g1, you can draw each char using these Rectangles:

```
public IEnumerable<Rectangle> GetRectangles(Graphics g1)
{
    int left = X;
    foreach (char ch in word)
    {

        //actual width is the (width of XX) - (width of X) to ignore padding
        var size = g1.MeasureString("" + ch, Font);
        var size2 = g1.MeasureString("" + ch + ch, Font);

        using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap((int)size.Width + 2, (int)size.Height + 2))
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
            g.TextRenderingHint = g1.TextRenderingHint;
            g.DrawString("" + ch, Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
            int top = -1;
            int bottom = -1;

            //find the top row
            for (int y = 0; top < 0 && y < (int)size.Height - 1; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < (int)size.Width; x++)
                {
                    if (b.GetPixel(x, y).B < 2)
                    {
                        top = y;
                    }
                }
            }

            //find the bottom row
            for (int y = (int)(size.Height - 1); bottom < 0 && y > 1; y--)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < (int)size.Width - 1; x++)
                {
                    if (b.GetPixel(x, y).B < 2)
                    {
                        bottom = y;
                    }
                }
            }
            yield return new Rectangle(left, Y + top, (int)(size2.Width - size.Width), bottom - top);
        }
        left += (int)(size2.Width - size.Width);
    }

}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create an invisible window for measurement purposes with exactly the same size and font settings what you have in the "real" window. After that you can deduct the individual bounding boxes of the characters by blending together more data:

- rectangle of the selection of the individual character, that can give indication of the left and right bounds of the character. Unfortunately the height of this is the full height of the row
- height from data from MeasureCharacterRanges() or similar technique

I agree with @Jason Williams though. "padding and fudge factors" can distort the results a little.

Answer (score 0):

If performance isn't critical, I would think you could get the most accurate results by converting the characters to paths and examining those.  I'm not sure the best way to handle kerning issues, but for fonts without ligatures one could probably figure out the bounding boxes for characters in isolation, measured relative to their starting points, and then determining the starting points of each character in the kerned string.  For fonts with ligatures, individual characters may not always *have* distinct glyphs.  For example, if a font has an "ffi" ligature, the word "offing" may contain only four glyphs: "o", "ffi", "n", and "g"; it would be meaningless to ask about the bounding box of the "i".

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to **stop** using Graphics.DrawString. I measured the characters by adding them to a GraphicsPath and getting the bounds from the GraphicsPath object. Then I draw the characters with Graphics.FillPath.

DrawString routine is optimized for drawing (more) text in a box. If you want to draw characters more precisely then DrawString is not sufficient. It adds space in front and after the text.

If you need precise character drawing, measure with GraphicsPath and drawing with FillPath is the way to go. Compared to looking up pixels as suggested in this thread and elsewhere GraphicsPath operations are blazingly fast.

If you also need Kerning then load the Kerning table from the font using DllImport on GetKerningPairs. For this, you also need the font in a Win32 friendly way. For that I suggest CreateFont.

Good luck!