# how to draw into image bounding box in c#

Tags: c#

i tried to draw into BMB image and i measure bounding box of each character i want to draw but nothing happen what's the wrong please ?

this is the code which draw the text

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imagepath);//load the image file
            Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
          PointF GLocation = new PointF(float.Parse(textBox1.Text), float.Parse(textBox2.Text));
         /* PointF XLocation = new PointF(float.Parse(textBox3.Text), float.Parse(textBox4.Text));
            PointF HLocation = new PointF(float.Parse(textBox5.Text), float.Parse(textBox6.Text));
            PointF ZLocation = new PointF(float.Parse(textBox7.Text), float.Parse(textBox8.Text));
            PointF YLocation = new PointF(float.Parse(textBox9.Text), float.Parse(textBox10.Text));
            PointF KLocation = new PointF(float.Parse(textBox11.Text), float.Parse(textBox12.Text));
            PointF FLocation = new PointF(float.Parse(textBox13.Text), float.Parse(textBox14.Text));
            PointF ELocation = new PointF(float.Parse(textBox15.Text), float.Parse(textBox16.Text));*/


            Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);
            grPhoto.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, newBitmap.Width, newBitmap.Height), 0, 0, newBitmap.Width, newBitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            //MessageBox.Show(measureAlphabet('G', arial).ToString());
            int x = (int)measureAlphabet('G', arial).Width;
            int y = (int)measureAlphabet('G', arial).Height;
            Rectangle rec = measureAlphabet('G', arial);
            for (int G = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); G <= G + x; G++)
            {
                for (G = int.Parse(textBox2.Text); G <= G + y; G++)
                {
                    Color pixelcolor = newBitmap.GetPixel(x,y);
                    if (pixelcolor.R != 255 && pixelcolor.G != 255 && pixelcolor.B != 255)
                    {
                        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap))
                        {
                            using (arial)
                            {
                                graphics.DrawString(firstchar, arial, Brushes.Blue, GLocation);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
           /* using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap))
            {
                using (arial)
                {
                    graphics.DrawString(secondchar, arial, Brushes.Red, XLocation);
                    graphics.DrawString(thirdchar, arial, Brushes.Brown, HLocation);
                    graphics.DrawString(fourthchar, arial, Brushes.DarkCyan, ZLocation);
                    graphics.DrawString(fifthchar, arial, Brushes.DarkGreen, YLocation);
                    graphics.DrawString(sixthchar, arial, Brushes.Coral, KLocation);
                    graphics.DrawString(seventhchar, arial, Brushes.Salmon, FLocation);
                    graphics.DrawString(eighthchar, arial, Brushes.SeaGreen, ELocation);
                }
            }*/
            bitmap.Dispose();
            //  newBitmap.Dispose();
            newBitmap.Save(imagepath);
        }
```

method which measure bounding box

```
 public Rectangle measureAlphabet(char alph, Font font)
        {
            SizeF size = CreateGraphics().MeasureString(alph.ToString(), font);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height);
            Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            grp.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            grp.DrawString(alph.ToString(), font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
            Bitmap img = (Bitmap)bmp;
            int x = 0, y = 0, width = 0, height = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
                    if (img.GetPixel(i, j).B < 2)
                    {
                        x = i;
                        goto jmp1;
                    }

            jmp1:;
            for (int i = img.Width - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
                    if (img.GetPixel(i, j).B < 2)
                    {
                        width = i - x;
                        goto jmp2;
                    }

            jmp2:;
            for (int i = 0; i < img.Height; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < img.Width; j++)
                    if (img.GetPixel(j, i).B < 2)
                    {
                        y = i;
                        goto jmp3;
                    }

            jmp3:;
            for (int i = img.Height - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                for (int j = 0; j < img.Width; j++)
                    if (img.GetPixel(j, i).B < 2)
                    {
                        height = i - y;
                        goto jmp4;
                    }

            jmp4:;
            Rectangle resultRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            return resultRectangle;
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497792/c-sharp-drawstring-measure-bounding-boxes-for-each-character).

Comment: i want to know what's the wrong in my code ? no charterer is drawing when i make for loop

Comment: You are creating one `Graphics` object too many. Simply use the one you have and do `grPhoto.DrawString(firstchar, arial, Brushes.Blue, GLocation);`. You are also __leaking__ the `Graphics` objects you create!